# Large MySQL Import - Does not error, but also does not appear to load the data

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to upload a relatively large SQL file onto my server using SSH.

The SQL file is 153MB and the command that I am using it

```
mysql -u <username> -p <password> < poem.sql
```

I get prompted for the password that is correct however I receive nothing after that (no errors messages etc) just goes straight to a new line in SSH and no database uploaded on phpmyadmin

Is the above the correct command for such a large database?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: You say "upload" but in fact you mean "import", the file is already on the server, correct? Just to be clear

Comment: MySQL. Yes, im trying to import from FTP

Comment: But poem.sql is already present in the directory you're calling mysql in, and it's 153 MB large? You checked using, say, `ls`?

Comment: Login, execute "show databases;" and verify that in fact the database was not created and the data was not imported.  MySQL stores tables in a schema.  If the 153M file is a dump from MySQL, it will create a database / schema and import the tables and data.  Try logging in and then "source poem.sql" and see if there is activity.